# Nullified the deportation rule ON/TO/FOR her

Tags: grammar, prepositions, phrases

Let's say your aunt got deported by the U.S government. Few weeks later, she came back, as the gov't has nullified the deportation rules because your aunt gave birth in the U.S.A (more like mandatory child support). The correct *phrase* & *preposition* is:

> My auny was deported, but few weeks later, the U.S. government found out that she gave birth to her youngest child in the U.S.A, then the government has **nullified/amend the deportation rule on/to/for her,** so she came back.

What is the correct **phrase** and **preposition** here?

Comment: **a** few weeks later ... that she **had given** birth ...   and **nullified** not "has nullified"

Comment: Oh I see, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Normally we would say **her deportation ruling**.  But if you wanted to be long-winded about it, you could say

... the deportation ruling *in respect to* her

The prepositions you suggest are not quite idiomatic.  There are native speakers would might say **on her** or **for her** there, but they would be likely to have a number  of "non-standard" forms in their speech.

Comment: Wow you nailed it!